# Dagger 2 reusable component

Tags: android, dependency-injection, dagger-2

with Dagger 2, I have a module that calls a web service.  I need to be able to call it with different parameters each time (basically a toggle in the backend, so just True or False will change). I am not seeing how I can pass these parameters to a Dagger 2 Module other than in the constructor, or with something injected as a part of an @Provides statement. I am very familiar with DI, as I do Spring development everyday, however, I am missing this aspect with Dagger 2. In a sense, I want to create the equivalent of a Spring @Service, or @Component with methods I can call with appropriate parameters to pass in. What am I missing with Dagger 2?

Is a module even the right object I want to create?

UPDATE: added some sample code.

Module:

```
@Module
public class RecordedProgramWatchedStatusModule {

    private int chanId = -1;
    private DateTime startTime = null;
    private boolean watched;

    public RecordedProgramWatchedStatusModule() { }

    public RecordedProgramWatchedStatusModule( int chanId, DateTime startTime, boolean watched ) {
        this.chanId = chanId;
        this.startTime = startTime;
        this.watched = watched;
    }

    @Provides
    @PerActivity
    @Named( "updateRecordedProgramWatchedStatus" )
    UseCase provideGetUserDetailsUseCase( DvrRepository dvrRepository, ThreadExecutor threadExecutor, PostExecutionThread postExecutionThread ) {
        return new PostUpdatedRecordedWatchedStatus( chanId, startTime, watched, dvrRepository, threadExecutor, postExecutionThread );
    }

}
```

Observable:

```
public class PostUpdatedRecordedWatchedStatus extends UseCase {

    private final int chanId;
    private final DateTime startTime;
    private final boolean watched;
    private final DvrRepository dvrRepository;

    public PostUpdatedRecordedWatchedStatus( final int chanId, final DateTime startTime, final boolean watched, final DvrRepository dvrRepository, ThreadExecutor threadExecutor, PostExecutionThread postExecutionThread ) {
        super( threadExecutor, postExecutionThread );
        this.chanId = chanId;
        this.startTime = startTime;
        this.watched = watched;
        this.dvrRepository = dvrRepository;
    }

    @Override
    protected Observable buildUseCaseObservable() {
        return this.dvrRepository.updateRecordingWatchedStatus( this.chanId, this.startTime, watched );
    }
}
```

Backend Handler:

```
@SuppressWarnings( "Convert2MethodRef" )
@Override
public Observable<Boolean> updateRecordingWatchedStatus( final int chanId, final DateTime startTime, final boolean watched ) {
    Log.d( TAG, "updateRecordingWatchedStatus : enter" );
    final DvrDataStore dvrDataStore = this.dvrDataStoreFactory.createMasterBackendDataStore();

    return dvrDataStore.updateRecordingWatchedStatus( chanId, startTime, watched )
            .doOnError( throwable -> Log.e( TAG, "updateRecordingWatchedStatus : error", throwable ) )
            .doOnCompleted( () -> dvrDataStore.recordedProgramEntityList( true, -1, -1, null, null, null ) );
}
```

Comment: Do you use only Dagger2 in your project ? I usually delegate Rest and WS calls to RxJava, so I create a dynamic Observable which receives parameters and go to the Dagger part with the value I need.

Comment: @LeonardoFerrari Yes, I am using Dagger 2 and RxJava as well in my project. The architecture is clean, so all the data access is in a subproject, which is getting injected back into the app with Dagger 2.  But I am just not seeing how to create something equivalent to a Spring Service where I can make calls to that when needed, not relying on a constructor to inject those parameters into the module. That seems to be the only examples I am finding.  Maybe what I am looking for is not the appropriate use of Dagger2.

Comment: Hmm I see, try posting some code, please, I'll see what we can do!

Comment: @LeonardoFerrari I updated the original ticket with some sample code from the app. Full code is here, but this stuff has not been committed at this time. Thanks for your help. https://github.com/MythTV-Clients/MythtvPlayerForAndroid

Comment: So you are just setting the 'watched' variable, but you have to instantiate all the stuff, right ? Anyway, I don't see another way of doing this rather than what you did here in your code.

Comment: Yes, that is correct, this will ultimately update the backend via a REST endpoint. The problem is I have to create this when the fragment is created. This action is tied to a button click. The user may want to update this repeatedly (for whatever reason, intentional or not). Relying on the constructor injection, however, only lets me fire this once. Unless there is a way to recreate the module (tied to the button click event).

Comment: So I see what's going on. In that case, I implemented something called DynamicUseCase, where you can pass parameters to your UseCase and inside the repository you retrieve them. Check you my project https://github.com/leonardo2204/Flow1.0.0-alphaExample/blob/master/app/src/main/java/leonardo2204/com/br/flowtests/domain/interactor/DynamicUseCase.java

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/108956/discussion-between-leonardo-ferrari-and-dmfrey).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I see what's going on. In that case, I implemented something called DynamicUseCase, where you can pass parameters to your UseCase and inside the repository you retrieve them. [Check you my project](https://github.com/leonardo2204/Flow1.0.0-alphaExample)

Take a look at: 
https://github.com/leonardo2204/Flow1.0.0-alphaExample/blob/master/app/src/main/java/leonardo2204/com/br/flowtests/domain/interactor/DynamicUseCase.java

https://github.com/leonardo2204/Flow1.0.0-alphaExample/blob/master/app/src/main/java/leonardo2204/com/br/flowtests/domain/interactor/GetContacts.java

https://github.com/leonardo2204/Flow1.0.0-alphaExample/blob/master/app/src/main/java/leonardo2204/com/br/flowtests/presenter/FirstScreenPresenter.java#L86-L89

You just inherit from `DynamicUseCase`, pass the variables in a Bundle and pass it as the UseCase bundle parameter, e.g:

```
public class GetContacts extends DynamicUseCase {

    private final ContactsRepository contactsRepository;

    @Inject
    public GetContacts(ContactsRepository contactsRepository, ThreadExecutor threadExecutor, PostExecutionThread postExecutionThread) {
        super(threadExecutor, postExecutionThread);
        this.contactsRepository = contactsRepository;
    }

    @Override
    public Observable buildUseCaseObservable(Bundle bundle) {
        return this.contactsRepository.getContactsFromPhone(bundle.getBoolean("mustHaveNumber", false));
    }
}

Bundle bundle = new Bundle(1);
bundle.putBoolean("mustHaveNumber", musthavenumber);
this.getContacts.execute(new GetContactsSubscriber(), bundle);
```

It's something like that !
Hope that helps !

Comment: This works great! My only change was to replace the Bundle with a Map as my domain layer is pure java with no Android dependencies.

Comment: Sure, the result is the same ! The advantage of Bundle is that it is lighter. Glad it worked !

Comment: Exactly, I want to keep that pure java. I am sure there are some lighter weight options I could use, but the Map suffices.

Comment: This has totally changed everything for my app.  Really great stuff. Was able to clean up a lot of stuff.  Thanks again for this.

Comment: No problem, really glad it helped !